# How to prove that $I\cdot detA = adjA\cdot A $ without assuming $A$ is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Suppose that $A$ is a square matrix and I is identity matrix with same size. If $A$ is invertible, it is easy to show that $I\cdot detA = adjA\cdot A$, by multiplying each side from the right with $A$ and multiplying the equation with $detA$ for the equation $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{detA} \cdot adjA$. My question is if we do not know matrix A is invertible, how can we prove that the equation above holds?

Comment: The computation of each component of $\operatorname{adj}(A)A$ by the definition of matrix multiplication is the same as expandin the determinant along column $i$, for the case of the entry in position $(i,i)$ and of computing the determinant along column $i$ after having copied column $i$ in column $j$, for the case of the entry in position $(i,j)$.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Laplace's_formula_and_the_adjugate_matrix) is what 'expanding a determinant along a column' means.

Comment: One general "meta" approach is to use the fact that every element of each side is just a polynomial function in the entries of $A$.  If two multivariate polynomials are not identical then they could only agree on a sparse set of inputs, but the set of invertible matrices is dense in the set of all matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us denote the $k$-th column of $A$ by $A_k$, and let us write the determinant of $A$ as a (multilinear) function of the columns of $A$ as:
$$
\det(A) = \det(A_1,\ldots,A_n).
$$
Then the $(ik)$-th entry of the adjugate matrix $B=\mathrm{adj}A$ is defined by
$$
B_{ik}=\det(A_1,\ldots,A_{i-1},e_k,A_{i+1},\ldots,A_n),
$$
where $e_k$ is the $k$-th column of the identity matrix. We can compute the $(ij)$-th entry of the product $BA$ as
$$
\begin{split}
(BA)_{ij}
&=\sum_kB_{ik}A_{kj}\\
&=\sum_k\det(A_1,\ldots,A_{i-1},e_k,A_{i+1},\ldots,A_n)A_{kj}\\
&=\det(A_1,\ldots,A_{i-1},\textstyle\sum_kA_{kj}e_k,A_{i+1},\ldots,A_n)\\
&=\det(A_1,\ldots,A_{i-1},A_j,A_{i+1},\ldots,A_n)\\
&=\delta_{ij}\det(A),
\end{split}
$$
yielding
$$
BA=\det(A)I.
$$